# How to compute matrix transform local/world on OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, transformation

I'm developing an **OpenGL** program where each object / entity contains **m_WorldPosition, m_WorldOrientation, m_WorldScale and m_WorldTransform** (Vector3, Quaternion, Vector3 and Matrix4f).

The problem is that these transformations are global. So I move, rotate and scale an object / entity I need to use a function that I did.

```
// C++
void HEntity::translate(const HVec3f& pos, const bool local)
{
    if(local) {
        m_WorldPosition += m_WorldOrientation.toMatrix3() * pos;
    } else {
        m_WorldPosition += pos;
    }

    m_NeedTransformUpdate = true;
}
```

I wanted to do the same as other software such as **Blender** or **Unity3D 3D** where each object / entity contains the variables **[position](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html), [localPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html), rotation, localRotation**...

I want a similar system. Where I have the variables position, localPosition, orientation, localOrientation, scale, localScale. But I do not know how to apply it to matrix Each object / entity.

Below is the function to compute the matrix.

```
// C++
void HEntity::updateTransform()
{
    m_WorldTransform.identity();
    m_WorldTransform.setRotationAxis(m_WorldOrientation.getAngle(), m_WorldOrientation.getAxis());
    m_WorldTransform.scale(m_WorldScaling);
    m_WorldTransform.translate(m_WorldPosition);

    if(m_pParent) {
        m_WorldTransform =  m_pParent->m_WorldTransform * m_WorldTransform;
    }
}
```

And the game loop

```
// C++ - Game loop

HGameObject* object = NULL;
int index = 0;

for(; m_ObjectCount; index++)
{
    object = m_pObjectList[index];

    glMultMatrixf(object->m_WorldTransform.getTranspose());

    // Draw current object

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use shaders? If you are learning OpenGL you should be using shaders, otherwise you won't use any of your knowledge in the real world.

Comment: In **Blender** don't need Shaders for local/world transform like position, orientation and scale. in **Blender** each object has worldPosition, localPosition, without Shaders. [See](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.localPosition)

Comment: Are you sure you know what shaders are? You can store local position as long as you transform it to world space when you render. Is that what you want to know? How to go from local to global in a hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, in my program each object has "worldPosition worldOrientation and Worldscale" as access variables. The problem is that are global changes, I want to implement "localPosition, localOrientation ..." I do not know how to apply the world and the local in the matrix for later use **glMultMatrix**. Sorry for the English, I'm using **Google Translator**

Comment: Can you explain the `m_WorldTransform =  m_pParent->m_WorldTransform * m_WorldTransform;` line in your code?  Why are you adjusting your WORLD matrix by the parent's WORLD matrix, if they're WORLD matrices already?

Answer (score -1):

You should:

- bind the shader with the modelview matrix for transforming the first object
- bind the buffer with the vertex data for the first object
- draw
- bind the shader with the modelview matrix for transforming the second object (or use the same shader and change only matrix through uniform)
- bind buffer with the vertex data for the second object
- draw

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503866/how-do-i-display-2-or-more-objects-in-opengl-model-view-projection-matrices)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this without using shaders.

Comment: then you can use glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYD6zDiI_3A) ... but nowadays you should be uisng shaders

Comment: I already did. What I want is to replace the function **translate** by variables, eg **object->m_LocalPosition Vecto3 = (0, 1, 0)** instead **object->translate (Vector3 (0, 1, 0), true)**